# rename files in a folder using find shell

Tags: shell, unix, sh

i have a n files in a different folders like abc.mp3 acc.mp3 bbb.mp3 and i want to rename them 01-abc.mp3, 02-acc.mp3, 03-bbb.mp3... i tried this

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='
' 
COUNT=1 
for file in ./uff/*;
do mv "$file" "${COUNT}-$file" let COUNT++ done
```

but i keep getting errors like for syntax error near 'do and sometimes for not found... Can someone provide single line solution to this using "find" from terminal. i'm looking for a solution using find only due to certain constraints... Thanks in advance

Comment: At minimum, you need a semicolon (or newline — that would be better) before `let` and before `done`.  If you want two digits in the numeric prefix, you're going to need to work a bit harder: `printf "%.2d-%s" "$COUNT" "$file"` would generate the format better.

Comment: Never mess with `$IFS`. I have literally never run into a good reason to use it, and it screws up your entire script.

Comment: @ParthianShot: 'Never' is an over-statement, but there is seldom a need to do it, and this is not one of those times (so I agree with the gist of your advice).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler im getting following after i tried your soln `mv: cannot move `./uff/ abc.mpp' to `1-./uff/ abc.mpp': No such file or directory
mys.sh: 7: mys.sh: let: not found
mv: cannot move `./uff/bbc.mpp' to `1-./uff/bbc.mpp': No such file or directory`
mys.sh: 7: mys.sh: let: not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably use:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ./uff || exit 1

COUNT=1 
for file in *.mp3;
do
    mv "$file" $(printf "%.2d-%s" ${COUNT} "$file")
    ((COUNT++))
done
```

This avoids a number of issues and also includes a 2-digit number for the first 9 files (the next 90 get 2-digit numbers anyway, and after that you get 3-digit numbers, etc).

Comment: mv: target `abc.mp3' is not a directory got the following error.. it didnt work for first file only.. but worked for rest

Comment: Not sure what you've done.  I created a directory `uff` and put 3 files in it.  Then I ran the script shown.  No dinking with IFS, etc.  The `cd` is important too.

Comment: that worked.. actually the first file name had a space in it at the start of the name... any hack to ignore space??

Comment: If the only space is at the start, you could drop the double quotes around `$file` in the `printf` command.  Or if there are more spaces, put double quotes around the `$(…)` part.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNT=1 
for file in ./uff/*;
do 
path=$(dirname $file)
filename=$(basename $file)

   if [ $COUNT -lt 10  ]; then
      mv "$file" "$path"/0"${COUNT}-$filename";
   else
      mv "$file" "$path"/"${COUNT}-$filename";
   fi

COUNT=$(($COUNT+1));

done
```

Eg:

```
user@host:/tmp/test$ ls  uff/
abc.mp3  acc.mp3  bbb.mp3

user@host:/tmp/test$ ./test.sh

user@host:/tmp/test$ ls uff/
01-abc.mp3  02-acc.mp3  03-bbb.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's the version without loops:

```
paste -d'\n' <(printf "%s\n" *) <(printf "%s\n" * | nl -w1 -s-) | xargs -d'\n' -n2 mv -v
```

You can also use `find` if you want:

```
paste -d'\n' <(find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%f\n") <(find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%f\n" | nl -w1 -s-) | xargs -d'\n' -n2 mv -v
```

Replace `mv` with `echo mv` for the "dry run":

```
paste -d'\n' <(printf "%s\n" *) <(printf "%s\n" * | nl -w1 -s-) | xargs -d'\n' -n2 echo mv -v
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution.

```
i=1
for f in $(find ./uff -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort)
do
  n=$i
  [ $i -lt 10 ] && n="0$i"
  echo "$f" "$n-$(basename "$f")"
  ((i++))
done
```

And here it is as a one-liner (but in real life if you ever tried anything remotely like what's below in a coding or ops interview you'd not only fail to get the job, you'd probably give the interviewer PTSD. They'd wake up in cold sweats thinking about how terrible your solution was).

```
i=1; for f in $(find ./uff -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort); do   n=$i;   [ $i -lt 10 ] && n="0$i";   echo "$f" "$n-$(basename "$f")" ;   ((i++)); done
```

Alternatively, you could just `cd ./uff` if you wanted the rename them in the same directory, and then use `find .` (along with the other find arguments) to clear everything up. I'm assuming you only want files moved, not directories. And I'm assuming you don't want to recursively rename files / directories.